# HATEOAS sort/order embedded resources

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-boot, hateoas

I have a pretty default hateoas spring boot application. And I'm wondering if it is possible to return results in an ordered/sorted fashion.

for example: `localhost/person/1/pets` returns a a list of pets in a random order.
I would like to order it by some column (name, breed, age or whatever).

Sorting is possible on the main resource (`/person?sort=age,asc`) but not on the embedded resources I think.

My initial approach was `localhost/person/1/pets?sort=name,asc` but this seems to have no effect.

Can this be done within the GET request? Or should I add extra Java code?

Comment: I found out that the @onetomany relationship can be annotated with `@OrderBy("name ASC")`. This is sufficient for my situation. However it would still be interesting to sort it by another field from a client perspective.

Comment: Is your repository extending `PagingAndSortingRepository`?

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis YES

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
linkTo(PersonController.class).slash("/?sort=age,asc").withRel("all");
```